# want to add/replace.show two fragments when radio button is checked

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have two `fragments` Created with their `layouts`..inside my `Activity`.
I have two `radioButtons`. .R1 and R2 defined in my activity
I have implemented `onCheckedChange()` but dont know how to add/replace `fragments` when `radioButton` is clicked

I want to show Frag1 when R1 is checked, and Frag2 when R2 is checked..

Please help and suggest the code

I have tried following code.. but doesn't work properly and shows error "Unfortunately Your app stopped"

### the code i tried is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  OnCheckedChangeListener
{
Fragment1 frag1; 
Fragment2 frag2;
FragmentManager manager;
FragmentTransaction transaction;
RadioGroup rg;
public void onCreate(Bundle b)
{
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg1);
    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);       
    RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb1);
    rb1.setchecked(true);

    manager = getFragmentManager();
    transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.frame1, frag1, "frag1");
    transaction.commit();
}

public void onCheckedChange(...)
{
   transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
   switch(group.getCheckedRadioButtonId())
       {
           case R.id.rb1;
                transaction.replace(R.id.frame1, frag1, "frag1");
                break;
           case R.id.rb2;
                transaction.replace(R.id.frame1, frag2, "frag2");
                break;
   } 
}
```

}

Comment: what is the error log

Comment: Can you add error log?

Comment: @VivekMishra .. recreated all things.. and got the solution.. now it is working.. thanks..

Answer (score 1):

```
Fragment1 frag1 = new Fragment1();
Fragment2 frag2 = new Fragment2();
FragmentManager manager;
FragmentTransaction transaction;
RadioGroup rg;

public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);
    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb1);
    rb1.setChecked(true);
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    manager = getFragmentManager();
    transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    switch (group.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
        case R.id.rb1:
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame1, frag1, "frag1");
            transaction.commit();
            break;
        case R.id.rb2:
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame1, frag2, "frag2");
            transaction.commit();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got to commit that transaction!

Also ensure that your fragments are instantiated correctly

Comment: hi.. i did the commit after switch.. forgot to mension..1st time if open activity Frag1 displayed but if i click on R2 another frag is displayed but then if i swich back to R1 error displays "Unfortunately your app stopped"..

Comment: Whoo..i did some corrections... now it is working as expected.. Thanks Very Much...for hint